# Complete VBA form from details already on the form

Tags: vba, forms, textbox, concatenation

I need your help again on something that should be easier to do. However, it could also be more complex than it seems.

Form as it should be displayed after code:

[image: Form as it should be displayed after code]

As you can see from the above form, I would like to write (paste) the value from boxes coloured in yellow, red and green to the list below 
3 command boxes.

I have not written any full code yet for this purpose and the coloured picture is done as an example without code.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

sMo = lstmonth
vDte = sMo & "1, " & cboyear
vMo = Month(vDte)

'set fiscal month ACTUAL year
If vMo > 4 Then vDte = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, vDte)

TextBox2 = TextBox1.Value & Format(vDte, "mmyy")
TextBox3 = "Sales Rebate Due - " & UCase(Format(vDte, "mmm yyyy"))

End Sub
```

I assume it is some sort of concatenate function but I get stuck to how to **convert the month into numbers** and **how to make sure the year corresponds to the month of the fiscal year**, as per the example, July 2017 but Jan. 2018 although the financial year box only display the year to which the fiscal year ends.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you ever so much.

Comment: *I have not written any code yet for this purpose* - then it's too early to ask. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. See how [mcve] can help you come up with a good description of the specific problem you're having. See the title says you're having a problem with populating a form's fields, but your question says you're looking for someone to provide code to convert a calendar month number into a fiscal calendar month number. Have you tried writing a function that does exactly that?

Comment: Does that look better?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want that logic to be hidden in some button click logic.

Make a function dedicated to that: you take a `Date` parameter, and return a string representing your formatted fiscal-calendar date - you can't use the standard `VBA.DateTime` functions, because these operate on the "civil calendar" which isn't lined up with your fiscal periods.

One way to do this would be to have 12-position arrays that hold the offsets to use for each period:

```
Public Function GetFiscalCalendarPeriod(ByVal value As Date) As String

    Dim monthPeriods As Variant
    monthPeriods = Array(9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

    Dim yearOffsets As Variant
    yearOffsets = Array(-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    Dim index As Long
    index = Month(value) - 1 'implicitly sized array is 0-based

    Dim periodMonth As Long
    periodMonth = monthPeriods(index)

    Dim periodYear As Long
    periodYear = Year(value) + yearOffsets(index)

    GetFiscalCalendarPeriod = Format$(periodMonth, "00") & Right$(Format$(periodYear, "0000"), 2)

End Function
```

That way you can easily get the "fiscal period" given any date, wherever you need that logic.

In the case of your dialog, you would take e.g. `2018-07-01` aka "July 2018", and the function would return a string e.g. `"0318"`, since July 2018 is the 3rd period in fiscal year 2018; give it `2018-02-01` aka "February 2018", and the function returns `"1017"`, as that's the 10th period of fiscal year 2017.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Very impressive. I didn't think it this way at all. Opens up new perspective for me.